# issue with clicking shadow dom anchor tag using selenium and java

Tags: java, selenium, hyperlink

I am learning selenium . i was trying to automate an hyper link click in developer.salesforce.com website. i wrote following code and when i execute the code i am getting JavascriptException in shadowContent.click() function saying **Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'defaultView')** Element: [[org.openqa.selenium.remote.ShadowRoot@327af41b] -> css selector: .button.variant_primary.size-hero.font-display.icon-right]

```
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://developer.salesforce.com");
    WebElement shadowHost = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//dx-button[@href='/get-started']"));
    SearchContext shadowRoot = shadowHost.getShadowRoot();
    WebElement shadowContent = shadowRoot.findElement(By.cssSelector(".button.variant_primary.size-hero.font-display.icon-right"));
    shadowContent.click();
```

Comment: please let me know where is the issue and how to rectify

Comment: Where do you want to click  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

I tried, it is working fine.

```
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
            
    WebElement rootEle = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//dx-button[@href='/get-started']"));
            
//  SearchContext expandedRooEle = (SearchContext) js.executeScript("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", rootEle);
//  (Or)
    SearchContext expandedRooEle = rootEle.getShadowRoot();
            
    WebElement button = expandedRooEle.findElement(By.cssSelector(".button.variant_primary.size-hero.font-display.icon-right"));
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", button);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It looks like the last line js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", button); is making difference but when we directly try using selenium web element method button.click() is not working. i dont know why it will not work.

Comment: when we click on a webelement using Selenium WebDriver , it checks two preconditions before clicking:-
The element must be visible.
It must have a height and width greater than 0.
If preconditions are not satisfied, you will get exceptions stating element is not clickable or interactable. But in JavaScript clicks does not check these preconditions before clicking. Refer: http://makeseleniumeasy.com/2019/06/15/selenium-interview-question-8-what-is-difference-between-webdriver-click-and-javascript-click-methods/

Comment: Always use Webdriver.click(), if it is not working (mostly it will work, but in some conditions, refer the above link), then use JavaScript click() as the last option.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to click on Get Started Button, you can try like below:

Frist try like:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//dx-button[@href='/get-started']")).click();
```

In case if you get the same error then share the error with us.

***Or you can try the below:***

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();

JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; 

WebElement getStartedButton = (WebElement) js.executeScript("return document.querySelector('#maincontent > div > div > div > dx-button').shadowRoot.querySelector('a')");
// now you can click on get Started Button ...
getStartedButton.click();
```

Comment: both of these approaches are not working. i already tested before posting this question. the first approach will not work as the element which i am trying to click is shadow dom element and i don't know why second approach is not working.

Comment: What error are you getting ?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'defaultView')
Element: [org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement@d0503db8 -> unknown locator]

Comment: i request you to test the code in your editor. i want to click on GetStarted Hyper link present in developer.salesforce.com website